# How can I write an EXISTS predicate on a collection attribute in Criteria API?

Tags: jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I have these classes:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany List<Customer> related;

}
```

and I'm using this JPQL query:

```
select c from Customer c where c.name = 'ACME'
    or exists( select 1 from c.related r where r.name = 'ACME' )
```

How can I write the same query with the Criteria API? I need to use `exists` with a subquery, like the JPQL, but I don't know how to create a subquery from a collection attribute in the Criteria API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would give `EXISTS (subquery)`

```
Subquery<Long> sq = cq.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Customer> customerSub = sq.correlate(customer);
Join<Customer,Customer> related = customerSub.join(Customer_.related);
... extra config of subquery

Predicate existsCustomer = cb.exists(sq);
```

where `cq` is the `CriteriaQuery`, and `cb` is `CriteriaBuilder`. This comes from an example in the JPA 2.1 spec p323 Example 4

Comment: How the subquery would be restricted to the `related` collection attribute?

Comment: Do a JOIN in the outer, and then apply a where clause in the subquery using that outer alias?

Comment: I cannot use `JOIN`s, I'm looking for the same resulting SQL query and the JPQL version does not produce any `JOIN`. I need something like `subquery.from( root.get( "related" ) )` but `from` wants entities not paths…